# $_POST is empty/null after form submission

Tags: php, jquery, post

Before we begin, I am fully aware of the billion other posts on this, but for some reason (poor coding on my part maybe) the answers don't apply.

This is the HTML my jquery targets:

```
<!-- data epids array -->
<form method="post" id="id-form" class="hidden">
    <input type="hidden" id="ids" value="" />
</form>
```

And essentially ids are added via jquery on page load. I've checked the data using `console.log($('#ids').val())` and it returns data as expected.

I then do this in my jQuery:

```
//export to csv
$('#to-csv').on('click', function(e)
{
    //stop default action
    e.preventDefault();

    //set form
    var form  = $('#ids-form'),
        ids   = $('#ids').val(),
        data  = [];

    var splitIds = ids.split(', ');

    for (var i = 0; i < splitIds.length; i++)
    {
        data.push({'id': splitIds[i]})
    }

    console.log(data); //this returns an object of correct data

    //set form url, data + submit
    form.attr('action', parts_url+ 'output-csv.php');

    //I didn't think this was necessary, with or without, $_POST is still null
    form.append(data); 
    form.submit()
});
```

To me this would work, but when I try using $_POST it's empty. I've tried viewing the data in the array like this:

```
var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));
var_dump($_POST);
```

The first returning an empty string and the second an empty array.

I'm not sure why it's null. Could it be I'm using one input for one array and there's an unspoken limit on char length from an input?

How do I go about debugging?

(p.s would it help to post my .ini file?)

Thanks.

## UPDATE

So I tried my last sentence:

changing HTML to:

```
<form method="post" id="ids-form" class="hidden">
    <!--<input type="hidden" id="ids" value="" />-->
</form>
```

my jquery to:

```
//export to csv
$('#to-csv').on('click', function(e)
{
    //stop default action
    e.preventDefault();

    //set form
    var form = $('#ids-form');

    //set form url, data + submit
    form.attr('action', parts_url+ 'output-csv.php');
    form.submit()
});

$('.rm-row').each(function()
{
    var id = $(this).data('id');

    $('#ids-form').append('<input type="hidden" class="id" value="'+ id +'" id="'+ id +'" />')
});
```

and post is still empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, `data` is an array. Hence `form.append(data)` will stringify the array and append it in the HTML as text. It is not adding any data to the request sent to the server.

Secondly, the `form` has an `id` of `id-form` yet the jQuery selects: `$('#ids-form')`.

Thirdly, your `$_POST` is empty because the `input` in the HTML has no `name` attribute.

```
<form method="post" id="id-form" class="hidden">
  <input type="hidden" id="ids" name="ids" value="" />
</form>
```

Once you've addressed those issues, your logic will work fine.

Comment: ah sorry this is just a typo in adding to question (real id uses a certain name I can't share :))

Comment: Which is a typo? The form `id` or lack of `name` on the `input`?

Comment: the form id - trying name now :)

Comment: you know when you feel really stupid? haha ty can't believe I overlooked this ^^ ty

Comment: Happens to us all :) Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
<!-- data epids array -->
<form method="post" id="id-form" class="hidden">
    <input type="hidden" id="ids" value="" />
</form>
```

Try this:

```
<!-- data epids array -->
<form method="POST" id="id-form" class="hidden">
    <input type="hidden" id="ids" name="abc" value="Something_data" />
</form>
```

Comment: the values are auto-generated jquery-side so this doesn't work but thanks :)

Comment: welcome, if value auto generated then why you use html?

Comment: because it's easier to append to dom then create full form with jquery